# primefaces datatable selected row always the same value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable with custom delete button when I try to send the id of the selected row to the backing bean, but i always get the same value, this is my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="result" var="service" value="#{bean.services}" editable="true"> 
<!--  ajax -->
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{bean.onEdit}" update=":form:msg" />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{bean.onCancel}" update=":form:msg" />   
.....
<p:column headerText="delete" style="width:100px;">
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmation" message="are u sure?" header="delete item" widgetVar="confirmation" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
<p:commandButton value="Yes"  onclick="PF('confirmation').hide()" actionListener="#{bean.onDeleteRow}">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.cve}" value="#{service.id.cve}" />
</p:commandButton>  
<p:commandButton value="No" onclick="PF('confirmation').hide()" type="button" />   
</p:confirmDialog>
<p:commandLink id="deleteLink"  onclick="PF('confirmation').show()" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"/>                              
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

here is the baking bean code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Bean implements Serializable{

private String cve;

...

public void setcve(String cve) {
    this.cve = cve;
}

....    

public void onDeleteRow(){

try {
System.out.println("delete-->" + this.cve );
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}

}
```

In the tag  you can see the value that I'm sending as a parameter but I always leave the last value of datatable ...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also there is another problem in your code, you have and Dialog for each row in the datatable, its a bad idea... you should keep the button on the row and set the entity that you want to delete when click at this button and latter just show the dialog, which is just one... something like this: also, change the propertyAcionListener to your delete link

```
<p:commandLink id="delete_link" oncomplete="deleteDlg.show();">
    Delete
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{service.id.cve}" target="#{bean.cve}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: what happens is that is a composite key (and im working with jpa2 for the backend)​​, so I'm getting the value that way, the problem is that every time you choose a different row the value of service.id.cve  is always the same i dont know why :(, thank you very much

Comment: @Mariah move setPropertyActionListener to inside your <p:commandLink id="deleteLink"  onclick="PF('confirmation').show()" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"/>

Answer (score 0):

Where is the selection for datatable?

your xhtml

```
<p:dataTable id="result" var="service" value="#{bean.services}" editable="true">
```

must be xhtml

```
<p:dataTable id="result" var="service" value="#{bean.services}" selection="#{bean.selected}" editable="true">
```

you can find datatable selection example [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml)

Comment: in this case I'm not taking selected because I wanted to pass as a parameter only id I need, not the entire object, anyway took your advice and did this:

<p:dataTable id="result" var="service" value="#{bean.services}" 
               editable="true" selection="#{bean.selectedService}" > .... and for the backing bean:  private Service selectedService; -- with setter and getter, but when I want to access it is null...